# Lane-Emden equation. Quasi-linearization method.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, physics, boundary-value-problem, mathematical-astronomy

How to prove this theorem? I have a doubt.

**Theroem:** Suppose that $w(x,\alpha)$ solved
$\ddot{w}+\frac{2}{x}\dot{w}+\alpha^{2}w=0$ with $w(0)=1$,
$\dot{w}(0)=0$, $w(1)=0$.
Then $v(x,\alpha) := \omega w(x,\alpha)$ solves
$\ddot{v}+\frac{2}{x}\dot{v}+\Theta^{2}v^{n}=0$ with $v(0)=\omega$,
$\dot{v}(0)=0$, $v(1)=0$ provided that
\begin{equation}
  \omega = \left(\frac{\alpha^{2}}{\Theta^{2}}\right)^{1/(n-1)}.
  \end{equation}

*Demonstration:*

- \begin{equation} v(0) = \omega w(0) = \omega 1 = \omega\end{equation}
- \begin{equation} \dot{v}(0) = \omega \dot{w}(0) = \omega 0 = 0\end{equation}
- \begin{equation} v(1) = \omega w(1) = \omega 0 = 0\end{equation}
- Substituting $v=\omega w$ into $\ddot{v}+\frac{2}{x}\dot{v}+\Theta^{2}v^{n}=0$ and cancelling common factors, we obtain $\ddot{w}+\frac{2}{x}\dot{w}+\alpha^{2}w^{n}=0$.

My question is:
$\ddot{w}+\frac{2}{x}\dot{w}+\alpha^{2}w=0$ then $\ddot{w}+\frac{2}{x}\dot{w}+\alpha^{2}w^{n}=0$? I guess not. I can´t demostrate this last part of the theorem.

Referene: Boyd, J. P. (2011). Chebyshev spectral methods and the Lane-Emden problem. Numerical Mathematics: Theory, Methods and Applications, 4(2), 142-157.

Comment: The equation should be $\ddot w + \frac{2}{x} \dot \omega + \alpha^2 w^{\color{red}{n}} = 0$, not $\ddot w + \frac{2}{x} \dot \omega + \alpha^2 w = 0$. Also it should be $n$, not $m$ in the definition of $\omega$. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lane–Emden_equation)

Comment: The theorem is never used in the paper http://www.nipne.ro/rjp/2017_62_1-2/RomJPhys.62.104.pdf, for their numerical experiments they use a standard linearization in the sense of the Newton method. The quasi-linearization idea surely exists and is for instance used in non-linear regression. But it is more a fixed-point iteration than a direct transformation. Can you find a source where the cited theorem is actually proven in some way?

Comment: That is not the paper. The correct paper is https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266836869_Chebyshev_Spectral_Methods_and_the_Lane-Emden_Problem . I suspect a typo in the first equation: $\alpha^{2}w$ should read $\alpha^{2}w^{n}$

Comment: Sorry, I got the wrong link of the open papers on the topic, the correct one is https://www.global-sci.org/v1/nmtma/volumes/v4n2/pdf/42-142.pdf. Note that the result of the quasi-linearization should be a linear problem, at least in some part of the result. The theorem in question seems like a bad reproduction of the quasi-linearization principle.

Comment: I see from another paper https://doi.org/10.1016/S0010-4655(01)00415-5 that the idea of quasi-linearization is just the Newton-like approach later used in the paper, see also https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Quasi-linearization. I was thinking of a more general pattern where if a problem can be written as $0=f(x)=p(x)-xq(x)$, one can construct an iteration from a linear combination of $x_n$ and $\frac{p(x_n)}{q(x_n)}$ or similar.

Comment: In that view, the cited theorem seems to reflect a mangled version of the transformation from a root-finding problem for an IVP to a quasi-eigenvalue problem for a boundary value problem.